# How to get the Android phone camera working with the MediaPipe Unity plugin?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-camera, mediapipe

I'm working on a project where I need to integrate the MediaPipe Unity plugin with the camera of an Android phone. I've been trying to set up the camera input using the WebCamSource class provided by the MediaPipe Unity plugin, but I'm encountering difficulties in getting it to work properly.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. I've included the necessary permissions in the Android manifest file to access the camera.
2. I've set up the WebCamSource class to initialize and start the camera input.
   However, despite these efforts, the camera input doesn't seem to be working as expected. I'm not seeing any video feed from the camera in my android phone(apk).

What are the correct steps to set up the Android phone camera as the input source for the MediaPipe Unity plugin?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

#if UNITY_ANDROID
using UnityEngine.Android;
#endif

namespace Mediapipe.Unity
{
    public class WebCamSource : ImageSource
    {
        private readonly int _preferableDefaultWidth = 1280;

        private const string _TAG = nameof(WebCamSource);

        private readonly ResolutionStruct[] _defaultAvailableResolutions;

        public WebCamSource(int preferableDefaultWidth, ResolutionStruct[] defaultAvailableResolutions)
        {
            _preferableDefaultWidth = preferableDefaultWidth;
            _defaultAvailableResolutions = defaultAvailableResolutions;
        }

        private static readonly object _PermissionLock = new object();
        private static bool _IsPermitted = false;

        private WebCamTexture _webCamTexture;
        private WebCamTexture webCamTexture
        {
            get => _webCamTexture;
            set
            {
                if (_webCamTexture != null)
                {
                    _webCamTexture.Stop();
                }
                _webCamTexture = value;
            }
        }

        public override int textureWidth => !isPrepared ? 0 : webCamTexture.width;
        public override int textureHeight => !isPrepared ? 0 : webCamTexture.height;

        public override bool isVerticallyFlipped => isPrepared && webCamTexture.videoVerticallyMirrored;
        public override bool isFrontFacing => isPrepared && (webCamDevice is WebCamDevice valueOfWebCamDevice) && valueOfWebCamDevice.isFrontFacing;
        public override RotationAngle rotation => !isPrepared ? RotationAngle.Rotation0 : (RotationAngle)webCamTexture.videoRotationAngle;

        private WebCamDevice? _webCamDevice;
        private WebCamDevice? webCamDevice
        {
            get => _webCamDevice;
            set
            {
                if (_webCamDevice is WebCamDevice valueOfWebCamDevice)
                {
                    if (value is WebCamDevice valueOfValue && valueOfValue.name == valueOfWebCamDevice.name)
                    {
                        // not changed
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else if (value == null)
                {
                    // not changed
                    return;
                }
                _webCamDevice = value;
                resolution = GetDefaultResolution();
            }
        }
        public override string sourceName => (webCamDevice is WebCamDevice valueOfWebCamDevice) ? valueOfWebCamDevice.name : null;

        private WebCamDevice[] _availableSources;
        private WebCamDevice[] availableSources
        {
            get
            {
                if (_availableSources == null)
                {
                    _availableSources = WebCamTexture.devices;
                }

                return _availableSources;
            }
            set => _availableSources = value;
        }

        public override string[] sourceCandidateNames => availableSources?.Select(device => device.name).ToArray();

        public override ResolutionStruct[] availableResolutions
        {
            get
            {
#if (UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IOS) && !UNITY_EDITOR
                if (webCamDevice is WebCamDevice valueOfWebCamDevice)
                {
                    return valueOfWebCamDevice.availableResolutions.Select(resolution => new ResolutionStruct(resolution)).ToArray();
                }
#endif
                return webCamDevice == null ? null : _defaultAvailableResolutions;
            }
        }

        public override bool isPrepared => webCamTexture != null;
        public override bool isPlaying => webCamTexture != null && webCamTexture.isPlaying;

        private IEnumerator Initialize()
        {
            yield return GetPermission();

            if (!_IsPermitted)
            {
                yield break;
            }

            if (webCamDevice != null)
            {
                yield break;
            }

            availableSources = WebCamTexture.devices;

            if (availableSources != null && availableSources.Length > 0)
            {
                webCamDevice = availableSources[0];
                InitializeWebCamTexture();
            }
        }

        private IEnumerator GetPermission()
        {
            lock (_PermissionLock)
            {
                if (_IsPermitted)
                {
                    yield break;
                }

#if UNITY_ANDROID
                if (!Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.Camera))
                {
                    Permission.RequestUserPermission(Permission.Camera);
                    yield return new WaitUntil(() => Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.Camera));
                }
#elif UNITY_IOS
                if (!Application.HasUserAuthorization(UserAuthorization.WebCam))
                {
                    yield return Application.RequestUserAuthorization(UserAuthorization.WebCam);
                }
#endif

#if UNITY_ANDROID
                if (!Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.Camera))
                {
                    Debug.LogWarning("Not permitted to use Camera");
                    yield break;
                }
#elif UNITY_IOS
                if (!Application.HasUserAuthorization(UserAuthorization.WebCam))
                {
                    Debug.LogWarning("Not permitted to use WebCam");
                    yield break;
                }
#endif
                _IsPermitted = true;

                yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
            }
        }

        public override void SelectSource(int sourceId)
        {
            if (sourceId < 0 || sourceId >= availableSources.Length)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid source ID: {sourceId}");
            }

            webCamDevice = availableSources[sourceId];
        }

        public override IEnumerator Play()
        {
            yield return Initialize();
            if (!_IsPermitted)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Not permitted to access cameras");
            }

            if (!isPrepared)
            {
                InitializeWebCamTexture();
            }

            webCamTexture.Play();
            yield return WaitForWebCamTexture();
        }

        public override IEnumerator Resume()
        {
            if (!isPrepared)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("WebCamTexture is not prepared yet");
            }
            if (!webCamTexture.isPlaying)
            {
                webCamTexture.Play();
            }
            yield return WaitForWebCamTexture();
        }

        public override void Pause()
        {
            if (isPlaying)
            {
                webCamTexture.Pause();
            }
        }

        public override void Stop()
        {
            if (webCamTexture != null)
            {
                webCamTexture.Stop();
            }
            webCamTexture = null;
        }

        public override Texture GetCurrentTexture() => webCamTexture;

        private ResolutionStruct GetDefaultResolution()
        {
            var resolutions = availableResolutions;
            return resolutions == null || resolutions.Length == 0 ? new ResolutionStruct() : resolutions.OrderBy(resolution => resolution, new ResolutionStructComparer(_preferableDefaultWidth)).First();
        }

        private void InitializeWebCamTexture()
        {
            Stop();
            if (webCamDevice is WebCamDevice valueOfWebCamDevice)
            {
                webCamTexture = new WebCamTexture(valueOfWebCamDevice.name, resolution.width, resolution.height, (int)resolution.frameRate);
                return;
            }
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot initialize WebCamTexture because WebCamDevice is not selected");
        }

        private IEnumerator WaitForWebCamTexture()
        {
            const int timeoutFrame = 2000;
            var count = 0;
            Debug.Log("Waiting for WebCamTexture to start");
            yield return new WaitUntil(() => count++ > timeoutFrame || webCamTexture.width > 16);

            if (webCamTexture.width <= 16)
            {
                throw new TimeoutException("Failed to start WebCam");
            }
        }

        private class ResolutionStructComparer : IComparer<ResolutionStruct>
        {
            private readonly int _preferableDefaultWidth;

            public ResolutionStructComparer(int preferableDefaultWidth)
            {
                _preferableDefaultWidth = preferableDefaultWidth;
            }

            public int Compare(ResolutionStruct a, ResolutionStruct b)
            {
                var aDiff = Mathf.Abs(a.width - _preferableDefaultWidth);
                var bDiff = Mathf.Abs(b.width - _preferableDefaultWidth);
                if (aDiff != bDiff)
                {
                    return aDiff - bDiff;
                }
                if (a.height != b.height)
                {
                    // prefer smaller height
                    return a.height - b.height;
                }
                // prefer smaller frame rate
                return (int)(a.frameRate - b.frameRate);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/homuler/MediaPipeUnityPlugin
when I install the apk, it doesn't ask for permissions nor does the camera work , pls help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.